# Get legend to display correctly using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to plot the observed vs. fitted values using ggplot; however, I can't get the legend to work. It only reports an entry for the observed values but not the fitted.

I recreated the issue with the iris dataset from fpp2.

Any advice on how to improve my code to include the legend heading for the fitted values?

```
data(iris)
fit = lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)
fit = predict(fit)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = "red")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit), size = 1, color = "green") +
  scale_color_identity(name = "Legend",
                       breaks = c("red", "green"),
                       labels = c("Observed", "Fitted"),
                       guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Comment: Move `color = "green"` inside `aes()` within `geom_line()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `color=green` into the aesthetic of `geom_line()`.

```r
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
fit = lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)
fit = predict(fit)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = "red")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit), size = 1, color = "green") +
  scale_color_identity(name = "Legend",
                       breaks = c("red", "green"),
                       labels = c("Observed", "Fitted"),
                       guide = "legend")
```

[image: Output from above code]

As a note, I might also consider changing "Fitted" to "Best Fit Line" or something similar, as seeing "observed" and "fitted" tends to make me think of [residual analysis](https://opexresources.com/analysis-residuals-explained/)